# Django Channels chat with one user

Tags: python, django, channel, django-channels

I completed my Django Channels.

I have confusion about. How to make conversation between two user (me and user2) only.

Is it possible to make conversation between only two user (me and user2) without making group

If I make group than anyone can join the group and the user2 need to join the group.

How can I send messages direct to the user2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think I did this by using a random string generator to create a unique room url and saved it in the database for both users